# snowflakes query profile -network communication

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

In  snowflake query "profile" in history tab  what is the significance  of values that we see for "Network"
As per the documentation :
"Network — network communication:
Bytes sent over the network — amount of data sent over the network."

Does this cost us?if it cost, does it costs under the compute cost (credits)?
          (or)
Does this cost under storage?

```
     (or)
```

Is this indirectly adds up compute cost as the query running longer because of high no.of bytes sent over network.?

What is recommendation to keep it low ,if it's not good to have high number ?

Comment: Not sure why this question was closed, but I'll answer you here.  The network bytes that are mentioned in your query profile have nothing to do with data transfer costs related to egress.  They are the amount of data that is being read from S3 to the VWH internally to Snowflake and are used for performance tuning in some cases.  Honestly, its not very useful information above using the # of microparitions scanned for the same purpose.

Comment: I agree with Mike !! When I started understanding snowflake these kind of questions were common to my mind as well

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think below two links will help you to understand the billing part of snowflake. Second link talks about when the **Data transfer will cost you and how**. The network on the query profile provides just the statistics on the data movement , billing components are defined clearly in these links.

- https://docs.snowflake.com/en/user-guide/admin-usage-billing.html
- https://docs.snowflake.com/en/user-guide/billing-data-transfer.html

Note on Data transfer from Snowflake document

```
Note that Snowflake does not charge data ingress fees; however, contact your 
cloud storage provider (Amazon S3, Google Cloud Storage, or Microsoft Azure) to 
determine whether they apply data egress charges to transfer data from their network 
and region of origin to the cloud provider’s network and region where your Snowflake 
account is hosted.
```